# Resolution refutation question confused

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm trying to solve this problem for my class. But now I'm so confused about the following question.

*Consider the following statements:

1. Every boy or girl is a child.
2. Every child gets a doll or a train or a lump of coal.
3. No boy gets a doll.
4. No child who is good gets a lump of coal.

a. Use the predicates BOY, GIRL, CHILD, GET-DOLL, GET-TRAIN, GET-COAL and GOOD to represent these statements as predicate calculus formulas.

b. Convert these statements to clauses.

c. Use resolution refutation to prove that if no child gets a train, then no boy is good.*

after first two-step, I can't prove the conclusion. One reason I think is that there is a girl function in the first clause, so I can't get an empty clause finally. The second reason is that I'm not sure whether I can use a clause many times to do the resolution refutation. Other similar questions are easy to prove by just using clause once and join them together, finally, I can get NIL or empty clause. But I can't prove this one. I don't know how to do.

[The working step 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLEXf.png)

[The working step 02(Please ignore this, I think the goal is wrong in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7jn2.png)

==============

[Goal and resolution refutation - 1(New version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g165D.png)

[Goal and resolution refutation - 2(New version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLrtG.png)

Comment: Can you please show the work you did so far?  It's possible that you didn't symbolize this right .. which could explain why you can't prove it.

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry, I didn't have enough reputation to add the picture. But I insert the link. I'm not sure whether it works.

Comment: Thanks, I see the pictures.  OK, you symbolized all premises correctly, but there is a problem with the conclusion. Can you show what you did there step-by-step? That is, first show the ecnclusion as is, then negate it, and work in the negation to show how you get to its clauses?

Comment: After considering the comment posted by you and @Thomas Maltuin, I think the goal is wrong. So I redo this part and continue doing the resolution refutation. And finally, I think I get the empty clause or NIL. But I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: No, still not right ... I give some more direction in my Answer below.

Comment: When proving by resoultion refutation, you need to negate the goal.  I checked over your notes and didn't find the goal negated.

Comment: I have already negated the goal. It is on the first few lines in the "Goal and resolution refutation -1".

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is still not good. You treat the goal as being just one big universal statement, but the goal is a conditional between two universal statements:

$$\forall x_5 (CHILD(x_5) \to \neg GET-TRAIN(x_5)) \to \forall x_6 (BOY(x_6) \to \neg GOOD(x_6))$$

Negating that, you get:

$$\forall x_5 (CHILD(x_5) \to \neg GET-TRAIN(x_5)) \land \neg \forall x_6 (BOY(x_6) \to \neg GOOD(x_6))$$

And thus both:

$$\forall x_5 (CHILD(x_5) \to \neg GET-TRAIN(x_5))$$

and

$$\neg \forall x_6 (BOY(x_6) \to \neg GOOD(x_6))$$

the first one is easily clausified:

$$\neg CHILD(x_5) \lor \neg GET-TRAIN(x_5)$$

but for the second one you get:

$$\exists x_6 (BOY(x_6) \land GOOD(x_6))$$

Now, do you know what to do with an existential?

Comment: I think what I learned from the course is just simply drop the existential quantifier, and don't need to replace all occurrences of the quantified variable by x5. So just get (6) ∧ (6) finally.

Comment: No. You keep thevariables when dropping a universal, so that you are still free to substitute anything fir tgat variable. But that doesn’t work for an existential; thete, you want to use a constant; it’s like saying: something has property P? Ok, let’s call that something Bob! In doing so, you keep other things from having that same property. That is, just because ‘Bob’ has property P does not mean *anything* has property P.

Comment: Uh...I know I need to use a constant or a new function to do the substitute. But for this question, I didn't see a constant here. Maybe I need to introduce a new function. So the clause will be (g(x5))∧(g(x5))?

Comment: @rocket  You need a *new* constant ... so even if you already had one, you would still need a different one. The logic of this is that *you don't know who the 'something' is that has the property as stated by the existential*.  However, in order to refer to this myusterious *something*, we are just giving it some name ... but *not some specific thing we already know about*, because we don't know if *that* specific object is the 'something'. So, like I said, we can call it 'Bob' ... even though we don't really know who is 'Bob" is. Anyway, you have no constant, so you can pick anything, say $a$

Comment: Ok, I think I have it cleared up now. Btw, I can use the clause as many times as I like to do the resolution refutation until I get the empty clause or NIL, right? Like what I did in the image.

Comment: @rocket Correct, you can use clauses any number of times, and indeed sometimes you have to in order to get to an empty clause.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @rocket My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

In formal logic I believe you can use a statement as many times as you like so long as it's derived or assumed (taken as an axiom) so if you have a statement at your disposal, you should be able to use it as many times as you like.  You need to think about what it means to negate a statement.

I believe you will need to create a formula for each of the 4 statements listed and join them with an AND connective. From what I just read on [resolution refutation](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~mei/logicp/unification-resolution/resolution-refutation.html) you should just need to cancel out conflicting terms as they appear.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I can use the clause many times, I think it will be easy to do the resolution refutation. And I also insert the image link to show what I have done so far. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't know what all you would have covered in this course, but I'd like to assume that you have gone over basic logical equivalences. The tricky thing with propositional logic is that everything has to be sound or you will run into problems.

Look at your "Negated Goal 5" in the second picture. I think you have a $\not$ that you don't need. I think you want $(\neg (Child \land GetTrain) \Rightarrow \neg (Boy \land Good) ) $which is logically equivalent to$ ((Child \land GetTrain) \lor \neg (Boy \land Good))$.

Comment: I think you are correct. The conclusion should be like what you did. And I update the goal and continue doing the resolution refutation. I think I got the solution, but not sure.